# Move multiple backgrounds infinitely using CSS

Tags: css, animation, background, css-animations

I have two backgrounds:

```
body {
    background-image: url(img/nemo.png),url(img/ocean.png);
}
```

How do I make `nemo.png background` move infinitely from left-right but not affecting `ocean.png background`?

**EDIT:** When he reaches the right most edge (and the image is no longer visible), he will appear from the left edge again and start doing the drifting from left-to-right.

Comment: You mean nemo swims back and forth?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by infinitely? When he gets to the right, does he appear from the left again, does he turn around and go back to the left?

Comment: I mean when it reaches the right most part, it appears on the left again. He doesn't turn back and go back.

Comment: So are you having problems moving nemo from left to right and then back again - or are you having problems moving _only_ nemo (since you're using multiple background images on the same element). If it's the latter, I think it would be easier to place the ocean on the html element and only have nemo on the body element. Then you could easily animate the body element's background position using jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done with pure CSS 3, e.g [keyframed animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dghsV/112

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://www.animaatjes.nl/disney-plaatjes/disney-plaatjes/finding-nemo/nemo11.gif"), url("http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/200022/ocean-dreams-blue-waves.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0%, 0;
    -moz-animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
    animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}
@keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}
```

### Syntax

> [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) : [`animation-name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name) [`animation-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration) [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) [`animation-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction);

The feature is experimental, so vendor-prefixes (eg `-webkit-`) have to be added (see also [Can I use CSS3 Animation](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) for compatibility notes). In my demo, I've used all properties, except for the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an option:

Create an animated GIF from the `nemo.png` which is a simple animation of the image moving from left to right.

Then create the layered backgrounds by setting `ocean.png` to the background of the `body` of your page.

Then create a `div` which with the following css:

```
width:100%; 
height:100%;
background-position:center center;
background-image: url(img/moving-nemo.gif);
```

The `div` will be an all-encompassing container for all of your content which will give you a layered background effect.

Comment: wouldn't this create many nemo images moving from left to right?

Comment: It depends how you make the animated gif. The gif should be one image of nemo swimming back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

make only ocean the background and create a div with the nemo as background:

```
<div id="nemo"></div>

#nemo {
    background: url(nemo.png) no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 500px;
    z-index:-10;
}
```

than you can animate this div with javascript (jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        SwimRight();
    });

//duration is in ms
function SwimRight() {
     $('#nemo').css({positionLeft: 0});
     $('#nemo').animate(
          { left: $(document).width() },
          { duration: 5000,
          easing: normal,
          queue: true, 
          complete: SwimRight}
     );
</script>
```