# How to use animationevent in css3

Tags: html, animation, css

So I am trying to learn new css3 features to get rid of javascript, but I have some problems with the animationevent "function". On w3.org it gives this definition:

```
interface AnimationEvent : Event {
    readonly attribute DOMString          animationName;
    readonly attribute float              elapsedTime;
    void               initAnimationEvent(in DOMString typeArg, 
                                          in boolean canBubbleArg, 
                                          in boolean cancelableArg, 
                                          in DOMString animationNameArg,
                                          in float elapsedTimeArg);
  };
```

So how should I use it in firefox or chrome? If anyone knows, please give a basic example of where should I write the animation name, like after animationName:, or after typerArg: should I put animationstart; I really have no idea. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface from the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#dom-interfaces) has to be implemented as follows:

```
e.addEventListener("animationend", listener, false);  
// listener is a function which receives an object implementing the
//  AnimationEvent interface.
```

This is DOM event. It's JavaScript. **The interface describes a DOM event, not a CSS feature.**

### Using CSS animations

To learn how to use CSS3 animations, read the [excellent guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations).
Visit [MDN: CSS/Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/animation) to get a concise page which links to the relevant documentation sections of each `animation` property.

Demo: I've prevously created a simple animation of a swimming fish. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108322/938089?move-multiple-backgrounds-infinitely-using-css) <sup>([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dghsV/))</sup>. Because it's an "experimental feature", you have to add *vendor-specific prefixes* to the CSS properties. So, `-webkit-animation-name` instead of `animation-name`.